# How does an I2C slave prevent data overrun?

Tags: i2c

By data overrun, I mean the inability of a slave to receive or acknowledge next byte from the master?
Any response would be appreciated.
Thank You!

Comment: You should explain more about what do you mean by 'data overrun'.

Comment: you may interpret as data overflow!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure what do you put into 'data overrun' term, but when the slave need some time to wait and "think" there is a mechanism called [clock stretching](https://www.i2c-bus.org/clock-stretching/).

Comment: Clock stretching has poor master support, anecdotally.